# How to use D'Alembert formula for Dirichlet boundary conditions on a finite interval?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, fundamental-solution

I have a wave equation to solve that I am not sure how to do. I know how to solve this using D'Alembert's formula without boundary conditions but I do not know how to solve it for Dirichlet boundary conditions.
\begin{equation}u_{t t}- u_{x x}=0, \quad u(x, t_{0})=f(x), \quad u_{t}(x, t_{0})=g(x), \quad   u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0 , \quad x \in (0,1) \quad t \in (t_{0},\infty)\end{equation}

Comment: The solution in this case is usually obtained by separation of variables and Fourier series.

Comment: by separation of the variables, I know how to treat it. But can't we use D'Alembert's formula?

Comment: As far as I know, d'Alembert's formula is applicable only to the one dimensional wave equation on the whole real line (or the half-line too for that matter) and not for bounded intervals.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I think you are right because me too I did not find D'alembert's formula for an interval bound.